# Problemas com aplicação ASP NET

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, visual-studio-code

Boa noite!

Estou iniciando meus estudos utilizando o ASP NET com o Entity, porém, por algum motivo metafisico, quando tento adicionar uma classe à pasta models não consigo acessar essa opção! O curioso é que já havia adicionado sem problemas outras 3 anteriormente, mas do nada essa opção "classe" não aparece mais no caminho Models>Adicionar>Classe! Alguém pode me ajudar? Muito provavelmente o problema é algo muito simples, mas como estou começando tudo é meio complexo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: No painel lateral esquerdo selecione a opção "Geral"

Comment: Selecionando "Geral" só fica disponível "Arquivo de informações do Assembly"